# How to recognize special markers on image in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I want to put buttons on layout by special markers (f.g. small circles). 
See picture below:

[image]

Final result maybe like this:

[image]

Whats the right way to do that? Most libraries and SDKs for image recognition              works with images from camera (almost in real time). In my case I have static image and its remain only recognize the special markers and then put buttons.

Comment: You might want to take a look at Java CV library https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv

Comment: @Gurupriyan I have installed javacv in my project over Graddle. But there is an erorr  during build process: `"Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'org/bytedeco/javacpp/windows-x86_64/api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll'"`

Comment: please post this issue as a separate question with your code.

Comment: @Gurupriyan thanx, I already clear how to use java OpenCV in Android (see my post below)

Answer (score 1):

I found this solve: [Detect Circle in image using OpenCV in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401343/detect-circle-in-image-using-opencv-in-android) and used it in my project. This works fine, but I have another problem (see this question: [How to convert Mat coordinates to Layout coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49324536/how-to-convert-mat-coordinates-to-layout-coordinates))

```
package com.example.aboev.matrix_sample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintSet;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FloorPlanActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Mat matBackground;
    Mat grayMatBackground;
    int colorChannels = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_floor_plan);

        ImageView imageViewFloorPlan = findViewById(R.id.imageViewFloorPlan);
        FileInputStream imageFileInputStream;
        Context context = this;
        // this double dimension array will contain X,Y positions of recognized circles
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();
        ConstraintLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.scrollingFloorPlanLayout);

        try {
            imageFileInputStream = context.openFileInput(getString(R.string.png_image_file_name));
            Bitmap imageFloorPlan = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageFileInputStream);
            imageViewFloorPlan.setImageBitmap(imageFloorPlan);

            matBackground = new Mat(imageFloorPlan.getHeight(), imageFloorPlan.getWidth(),
                    CvType.CV_8UC1);
            grayMatBackground = new Mat(imageFloorPlan.getHeight(), imageFloorPlan.getWidth(),
                    CvType.CV_8UC1);
            Utils.bitmapToMat(imageFloorPlan, matBackground);
            colorChannels = (matBackground.channels() == 3) ?
                    Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY : ((matBackground.channels() == 4) ?
                        Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY : 1);
            Imgproc.cvtColor(matBackground, grayMatBackground, colorChannels);

            Imgproc.GaussianBlur(grayMatBackground, grayMatBackground,
                    new Size(9, 9), 2, 2);
            double dp = 1.5d;
            double minDist = grayMatBackground.rows() / 16;
            int minRadius = 10;
            int maxRadius = 20;
            double param1 = 70;
            double param2 = 50;


            Mat circles = new Mat(imageViewFloorPlan.getWidth(), imageViewFloorPlan.getHeight(),
                    CvType.CV_8UC1);
            Imgproc.HoughCircles(grayMatBackground, circles,
                    Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp, minDist, param1,
                    param2, minRadius, maxRadius);
            int numberOfCircles = (circles.rows() == 0) ? 0 : circles.cols();

            if (circles.empty() || circles.get(0, 0).length == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.msg_circles_not_found),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                for (int i=0; i<numberOfCircles; i++) {
                    double[] circleCoordinates = circles.get(0, i);
                    final int x = (int) circleCoordinates[0], y = (int) circleCoordinates[1];
                    Point center = new Point(x, y);
                    int radius = (int) circleCoordinates[2];
                    Imgproc.circle(matBackground, center, radius, new Scalar(0,
                            255, 0), 4);
                    Imgproc.rectangle(matBackground, new Point(x - 5, y - 5),
                            new Point(x + 5, y + 5),
                            new Scalar(0, 128, 255), -1);

                    coordinates.add( new ArrayList<Integer>() {{ add((int) x); add((int) y); }} );
                }
            }

            Utils.matToBitmap(matBackground, imageFloorPlan);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            imageFileInputStream = context.openFileInput(getString(R.string.table_image_file));
            if (!coordinates.isEmpty()) createImgButton(context, BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageFileInputStream), coordinates);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    // This method creates buttons in the centers of recognized circles 
    private void createImgButton(Context context, Bitmap foregroundImage, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> coordinates) {
        ConstraintLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.scrollingFloorPlanLayout);
        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        constraintSet.clone(layout);

        for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.size(); i++) {
            ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(context);
            btn.setImageBitmap(foregroundImage);
            btn.setId(ViewIdGenerator.generateViewId());
            layout.addView(btn);
            constraintSet.clone(layout);
            // I tried to get real coordinate like this:
            double x = (coordinates.get(i).get(1) * 1080) / 480;
            double y = (coordinates.get(i).get(0) * 1920) / 640;
            constraintSet.connect(btn.getId(), constraintSet.TOP, layout.getId(), constraintSet.TOP, (int) x);
            constraintSet.connect(btn.getId(), constraintSet.START, layout.getId(), constraintSet.START, (int) y);
            constraintSet.applyTo(layout);
        }

    }

}
```

It looks like this:

[image]